# Not authorized to control networking in SSH console

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, networkmanager

I want to control Network manager from the command-line. This worked well enough in Ubuntu 10.04 (with cnetworkmanager, nmcli is another possible choice).

Since the upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10 however, a D-Bus exception is raised when I attempt to activate a connection from within a **SSH terminal**:

> org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.PermissionDenied:
>   Not authorized to control networking.

It may have to do with /etc/dbus-1/system.d/NetworkManager.conf; where else to look for a clue ?

This issue occurs only when I am **ssh**'d into the machine;
in a gnome session I don't get the same issue -- with the same (admin) user account in both cases.

Answer (score 14):

On more recent Ubuntu's this is control by the polkit.

make new file: `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/allow-ssh-networking.pkla`

Add:

```
[Let adm group modify system settings for network]
Identity=unix-group:adm
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control
ResultAny=yes
```

Then restart the `polkit` service. (Make sure your user is in the **adm** group)

You can find a list of valid NetworkManager actions on your system with `pkaction | grep NetworkManager`

More info: https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?276493-Remotely-starting-a-VPN-connection-does-not-work

Comment: For Raspbian (tested on Buster), you need to replace `/etc` with `/var/lib`

Comment: this works great on ubuntu 18.04 :)

Comment: For me this just changed the error message to `Failed to add/activate connection. (32) Insufficient privileges`. What solved was this: https://askubuntu.com/a/752168/63606

Comment: Even works on Ubuntu 16.04LTS (*sigh* yes this box should be updated but ‍♂️). Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

By default, DBus only allows `root` and users sitting at the physical console to control networking settings.

This can be changed by editing DBus policy files, in this case `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/NetworkManager.conf`

Comment: Any idea for Fedora boxes?

Comment: on my Mint 17.2 system the necessary file is called org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.conf

Comment: This answer is outdated, sometime I'll update it for the proper way using polkit. Until then, see https://gist.github.com/grawity/3886114

Answer (score 0):

Polkit v122 uses **javascript** for rule files, INI syntax was deprecated. This worked for me:

```js
/* Allow adm group to use nmcli con up/down over ssh */
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (subject.isInGroup("adm") && (
            action.id === "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.enable-disable-network"
         || action.id === "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control"
        )
    ) {
        return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
})
```

— placed as `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/authorize-ssh-nmcli.rules`; `systemctl restart polkit` to apply.